# Find the nth item in the mth permutation of a set, without generating the whole set

Tags: combinatorics

I want to map the integers from, say, zero to one million to themselves, such that there's no obvious pattern to the mapped results, and such that I can cheaply look up an arbitrary result by its index.

I could have sworn that I saw a library which does this years ago-- It let you give an index to choose a permutation, and then an index for the item in the permutation, and did this cheaply (in O(1) time). I can't remember the name of the concept or algorithm now, though, so I can't find it.

Does anyone know the name of an algorithm that does this?

Comment: Look for Factorial Number System.

Comment: This was it, thank you!